# animate bootstrap accordion panel-title on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-accordion

trying to animate the margin-left property of the panel-title on bootstraps accordion component. I've tried using .toggle() but it just does some weird bug. I've tried a few different methods but none seem to work. you can check it out here [codepen](https://codepen.io/fernandob/pen/RVLKNy)

```
 //Method Onee By Adding A Class
  $('.panel-title').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('open-panel') 
  }) 

 $('.panel-title').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('open-panel') 
  }) 

  //Method Two By Click but just animates open and closes right after another
  $('.panel-title').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({"margin-left": '+=20'});
  }),

  $('.panel-title').click(function(){
  $(this).animate({"margin-left": '-=20'});
  });

//Method Three the panels shrink among themselves cause of toggle()
  $(".panel-title").toggle(
    function () { 
    $(this).animate({"margin-left": "+50px"}); 
    },
    function () { 
      $(this).animate({"margin-left": "0px"}); 
});
```

Comment: What is wrong with Method one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `CSS` part as:

```
.panel-title {
   margin-left: 0px;
   transition: all 1s;
}

.open-panel {
   margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Also your `Method one` as:

```
//Method One
$('.panel-title').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $(".panel-title").not($this).removeClass('open-panel');
    $this.toggleClass('open-panel') 
});
```

Is that what you want?

**Update**
I realized you updated your pen, so you need to comment out some other JS to my mentioned code works correctly, [**here**](http://codepen.io/m-dehghani/pen/BRwRwr) is updated pen

Comment: this was it, thanks man! just a quick question, if i wanted the panel to slide back left when i clicked on another panel, how would I go on doing that?

I tried using the show.bs.collapse but it's pretty glitchy and funky.

Comment: Don't worry, glad to help. I updated my answer and the pen, please re-check them, let me know if something was not correct